# php alternating in pairs while loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

**Situation:** On my WordPress site I am outputting posts on my archive PHP template and I want to assign every second *pair* ( after the first post ) a CSS class of 'slim' and have the remaining get the class 'wide'. Furthermore, I would like to have the last post get a class of 'full'.

**Problem:** I'm not able to write the code so I can assign every second pair the class of 'slim'.

Here is a quick [drawing of the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxku8.jpg)

My current code works for the most part just not sure how to go about assigning classes to the pairs. Here is my code so far:

```
    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <header class="page-header">
            <?php the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
        </header><!-- .page-header -->

        <?php
        // Start the Loop counter:
        $client_post_index = 0;
        while ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php the_post(); ?>


            <?php 
            // check if a new row is needed.
            if ( $client_post_index % 2 == 0 ) : ?>
                <div class="work-archive-row">
            <?php endif ?>
                <?php 
                // check if the entry is odd or even and assign wide or slim class.
                if ( $client_post_index % 3 == 0 ) : ?>
                    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class='work-archive-post-wide'>
                        <?php twentynineteen_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </div>

                <?php else: ?>
                    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class='work-archive-post-slim'>
                        <?php twentynineteen_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </div>

                <?php endif ?> 




                <?php $client_post_index++; ?>
                <?php if ( $client_post_index % 2 == 0 ) : ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif ?>


        <?php  endwhile;

        // Previous/next page navigation.
        twentynineteen_the_posts_navigation();

        // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
    else :
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/content', 'none' );

    endif;
    ?>
    </main><!-- #main -->
</section><!-- #primary -->
```

The used CSS is as follows:

```
.work-archive-row {
height: 500px;
margin: 16px calc(5% + 60px) 8px calc(5% + 60px); }

.work-archive-row .work-archive-post-odd {
max-width: calc( 65% - 16px);
width: 100%;
margin: 0 8px;
float: left;
height: 500px;}

.work-archive-row .work-archive-post-even {
width: calc( 35% - 16px);
float: left;
height: 500px;
margin: 0 8px;}

.work-archive-row .work-archive-post-odd img {
height: 500px;
object-fit: cover;}

.work-archive-row .work-archive-post-even img {
height: 500px;
object-fit: cover;}
```

**UPDATE:** Another example - Let's say my archive loop spits out 10 posts then I need the posts to be assigned classes as following:

- Post 01: Wide
- Post 02: Slim
- Post 03: Slim
- Post 04: Wide
- Post 05: Wide
- Post 06: Slim
- Post 07: Slim
- Post 08: Wide
- Post 09: Wide
- Post 10: full

As you can see from the attached image each row will only contain two entries but I need the size ( CSS Class ) to alter.

Any pointers or reference to what that type of loop iteration is called would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You appear to be dividing by 3 and using the remainder, I think you want to check for `$client_post_index % 2 == false`

Comment: And see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25591/is-there-an-if-statement-that-can-determine-if-a-post-in-the-loop-is-the-last-po That explains how to detect the last post

Comment: @simon.ro ace thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using `% 3 == 0` as your test, this isn't how you can test for odd and even, if the value is 2, then the result will be 2 and not 0 or 1.

You need to use `% 2 == 0`

```
// check if the entry is odd or even and assign wide or slim class.
if ( $client_post_index % 2 == 0 ) : ?>
```

A simple way of alternating this is to have a state array and use the index % 4 as the index, so replace...

```
        <?php 
        // check if the entry is odd or even and assign wide or slim class.
        if ( $client_post_index % 3 == 0 ) : ?>
            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class='work-archive-post-wide'>
                <?php twentynineteen_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>

        <?php else: ?>
            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class='work-archive-post-slim'>
                <?php twentynineteen_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>

        <?php endif ?>
```

with

```
<?php $state = ['wide', 'slim', 'slim', 'wide']; ?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class='work-archive-post-<?php echo $state[$client_post_index % 4]; ?>'>
    <?php twentynineteen_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. true your comment would allow me to get odd / even but I need to do it in pairs as I tried explaining with the drawing. so I need:
Post 1: Odd
Post 2: Even
Post 3: Even
Post 4: Odd
Post 5: Odd 

etc – does that make sense? I am asking because I am not sure how best to explain that it's pairs I'm looking to work on.

Comment: absolut legend you! worked like a charm and a super neat write up. much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
1. row: wide/slim
2. row: slim/wide
3. row: wide/slim
etc.
```

=> odd row: wide/slim and even row: slim/wide

So just introduce another variable that increments with every row. Check for every post if you are in an even or an odd row and set the css classes accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @SimonRo - Nigel gave a plug n play solution so I have him the correct, but thank you for pitching in.